# node.js - generating 1000s of images causing heavy load

Tags: node.js, imagick, graphicsmagick

i am new to node.js.
I want to generate a number of images by imagick,gmagick for testing purposes.
The images should be name from 000001.jpg to 0x.jpg.
For the later testing i need about 50.000 images.

```
var async = require('async');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.


var number = parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 20;
console.log("Generating " + number + " images");

var pad = "000000";
var img_names = [];
for (i=1;i<=number;i++) {
    var str = "" + i;
    var padded_str = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str;
    img_names.push(padded_str+".jpg");
}

async.forEach(img_names, function (item, callback){ 
    console.log(item); // print the key
    gm(800, 600, "#ddff99f3").font("Helvetica.ttf", 80)
    .drawText(150, 300, "# "+item)
    .write("./"+item, function (err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    }); 
    callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed

}, function(err) {
    console.log('iterating done');
});
```

The proble is, when using a higher amout of images, the ubuntu machine starts a huge number of "convert" processes and gets into heavy load.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Kind regards, Robert

Comment: Dont use async? You are kind of fork bombing your own machine I think...

Comment: Process less images? Skip every *n* one? Upgrade to a quantum processor which offloads to a parallel universe?

Comment: it doesn't matter how long the generation will last ... but i should not "kill" the machine ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `callback()` function into the write function's callback, as the iteration has just forked `gmagick`, and not actually waited for it to finish. When it finishes, it calls its own callback - this is the end of the iteration, so it's where the `forEach()` function's callback should be called.

Moving `callback()` as above will block the `async.forEach()` until the `gm()` function has finished.

If you have a multicore machine you can run this function in parallel, approximately one worker process per core/hyperthread is a sensible default. Swap `forEach` for  [`eachLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) and set parallelism to 8:

```
async.eachLimit(img_names, 8, function (item, callback){ 
    console.log(item); // print the key
    gm(800, 600, "#ddff99f3").font("Helvetica.ttf", 80)
    .drawText(150, 300, "# "+item)
    .write("./"+item, function (err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed
    }); 

}, function(err) {
    console.log('iterating done');
});
```

Comment: But that will force it to do the image processing one at a time, waiting for each one to complete before starting the next. It would be more efficient to process multiple images simultaneously, as long as there aren't too many processing at once.

Comment: @MikeScott I've edited to clarify swapping `forEach` for `eachLimit`